# Website Page Redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns, cpanel

I have an odd, frustrating issue me nor my host can figure out.

- I use a Wordpress website with cPanel, and WHMCS installed on /clients/.
- I recently migrated a new website from a different web server into the production one, overwriting the plugins and data.

So the issue is that when I navigate to http://volarushosting.com/clients/ which is my WHMCS directory, it redirects the URL to /client-area/ which is a Wordpress page running a plugin to display my WHMCS portal without leaving the web page. I have that in place because we used to have it setup that way, but now I want to use WHMCS directly.

I noticed however, that you don't have to go to /clients/ to be redirected, even simply typing in /cl/ will redirect you. Tested on an Incognito page to ensure the browser is not caching.

I thought it might have been .htaccess, which did have a rule I put in to redirect, but I have removed that rule with no luck. I also had a Plugin in wordpress that did some redirecting but the migration deleted it. I tried removing my caching plugins (W3 total cache and Autoptimize) and their data with no luck. I checked cPanel for any redirects and cant find any.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this redirect? It seems to be trying to correct the URL to the nearest wordpress page perhaps. I'm not sure.

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but I'd recommend following the advice in this answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070459/3975904 -- This will setup a rewrite log that you can review to see if you can find the source of the strange redirect.. good luck, post back if you find anything out with this approach!

Comment: The redirect comes from within the page code, not from .htaccess

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I don't have permission to use the RewriteLog directive since it only allowed in the server or virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another .htaccess file in the WHMCS directory that had a rewrite regulator expression. Removing that resolved the issue.